# Image of the upper Half-space is the upper Half-Space

Tags: complex-analysis

In an exercise I stumbled over the mapping $\Phi:z\mapsto \frac{1+z}{1-z}$ where $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$. It is then stated without proof, that $\Phi:(\mathbb H)=\mathbb H$ where $\mathbb H$ is the upper Half-space. But when I try to prove this statement, I seem to get nowhere. I started with $z=re^{i\varphi}$ where $0<\varphi<\pi$, but I can't conclude that $\Phi(z)\in\mathbb H$.

Further I thought that the statement might be wrong:  $\Phi$ is a Möbius transformation with $M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\det(M)=2$, and I think I remember a statement about the automorphisms of the upper half space being Möbis transformations with $M\in SL(2,\mathbb R)$, and thus we would need $\det(M)=1$. So where am I wrong with this or is the statement in the exercise wrong?

Comment: Note that $z \mapsto \frac{\sqrt{1/2} + z\sqrt{1/2}}{\sqrt{1/2}-z\sqrt{1/2}}$ is the same map, but this time the determinant is $1$. The only reason we demand that the determinant should be $1$ is because it "uniquifies" the fraction up to a sign. The really important thing is that the determinant is a _positive, real number_.

Comment: @Arthur so the automorphisms of the upper half space can really be möbius transformations with positive determinants?

Comment: Yes, since as I demonstrated, any such fraction can be rewritten into an equivalent fraction with any other positive determinant.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\frac {1+z}{1-z} = \frac{(1+z)(1-\overline z)}{|1-z|^2} = \frac{1-|z|^2 + 2i\text { Im } z.}{|1-z|^2}$$

So if $\text { Im } z > 0,$ the same is true of its image.

Another approach: This is a linear fractional transformation. So the image of a half plane is either a half plane or a disc. Since the real line gets mapped to the real line, it has to map the upper half plane to a half plane with the real line as its boundary. So the image is either the upper or lower half plane. Check to see that $i$ gets sent to the upper half plane, and then you're done.